# the symbol for translation, transformation, or conversion

Tags: notation

What is the symbol for demonstrating syntactic conversion (transformation or translation)? For example, I want to show a calculation sequence, from $ \neg ( A \wedge B ) $ to $ \neg A \vee \neg B  $. Now I just use $ \vdash $: $ \neg ( A \wedge B ) \vdash \neg A \vee \neg B  $. Is there a suitable symbol to replace $ \vdash $?

Thank you.

Kejia

Comment: http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html might help if you already know the symbol you want to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

P :⇔ Q means P is defined to be logically equivalent to Q. This could be a suitable substitution, but I believe what you are using is best suited, since it is literally translated as "is derived from."

Comment: The same symbol have different meaning in different literature :-) Mathematics is always evolving.

Answer (score 0):

You could use both $\Leftrightarrow$ (`\Leftrightarrow`) and $\equiv$ (`\equiv`), meaning that the statements are logically equivalent.

Comment: You might also prefer $\iff$ (`\iff`), since it is easier to type.

Comment: That's a nice one! Even better since $\Longleftrightarrow$ (`\Longleftrightarrow`) is even worse ;) I think there is something like `\newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}` ;-)

Answer (score -1):

The symbol $\Rightarrow$ (or simply =>)
 would be my answer for a symbol for transformation, but I think it would be better if it were a single character symbol.